# linux "make oldconfig" discards an entry CONFIG_K8_NB

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, config

I have a .config in the top directory with CONFIG_k8_NB=y, however, after I type "yes "" | make oldconfig", the "CONFIG_k8_NB=y" is gone.

I am certain the CONFIG_k8_NB can be supported by the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I have found why, it's caused by the dependency of the configuration:
in arch/i386/Kconfig
config K8_NB
        def_bool y
        depends on AGP_AMD64

we should add:
CONFIG_AGP=y
CONFIG_AGP_AMD64=y
to enable K8_NB

there is a pointer talking about the issue:
http://www.kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/linux-kernel/2010/3/8/4545694